# If I'm using Guid Identity Web Api 2 It gives me an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

So here is my Exmaple:
Model:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my Web Api 2 Controller Part:

```
// POST: api/Items
[ResponseType(typeof(Item))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItem(Item item)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    item.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    db.Items.Add(item);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = item.Id }, item);
}
```

On insert I receive an error, but if I use string and `Guid.NewGuid().Tostring();` everything works fine, there is no problem to develop my App in this way but I want understand what is the problem, using GUID like this works on  MVC5.

Comment: A database cannot use a GUID Object as a PK, that's why it needs to be a string to get the strong content of the guid

Comment: i think you are using the column with identity this might create a problem with autographing the column ID as primer Key.
  
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of using `Guid` as your Id type, It can't be defined to be an property identity, so
remove this annotation above your Id:

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

and add `Guid.NewGuid()` in constructor of your model:

```
[Table("Items")]
public class Item
{
    public Item(){
      Id=Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then don't set your Id to `Guid.NewGuid()`, just make a new object of your class.